# Accepting data in a particular format

Tags: c#

My program has to accept the date entered by a user in this format month,date,year(mm/dd/yyyy) and not in any other sequence and if the details entered is in this format(mm/dd/yyyy) it gets stored in the multidimensional array.

Comment: windows forms? Web forms? (also, didn't you just ask a question like this?)

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the proper format string and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

```
dates[0] = DateTime.ParseExact("07/28/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`/` normally is a replacement char for your current culture's date separator (e.g. `-` or `.`). To enforce `/` as separator you need to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

See: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to check if the user has entered valid format:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("07/28/2013", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{ 
    // valid date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user inputs the date in a TextBox

```
        DateTime Test;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox1.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out Test) == true)
            //do whatever
        else
            //do something else
```

Comment: `null` as third parameter means _current culture_. So this format will be translated to `"mm-dd-yyyy"` or `"mm.dd.yyyy"` according to the actual date separator.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this, Tim!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> it has get stored in the multidimensional array.

Here's a complete program that prompts the user for a date in the format you specified.

```
void Main()
{
    string datePrompt = "Please enter the date mm/dd/yyyy: ";
    string invalidDateMessage = "Invalid date format, please use mm/dd/yyyy, for example you could type 01/07/1980.";

    DateTime dateTime;
    bool done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        string userInput = Prompt(datePrompt, Console.Out, Console.In);
        done = ValidateAndParseDate(userInput, out dateTime, Console.Out, invalidDateMessage);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("I can now store {0} in a multi dimensional array!", dateTime.ToShortDateString());
}

string Prompt(string prompt, TextWriter writer, TextReader reader)
{
    writer.Write(prompt);
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    return line;
}

bool ValidateAndParseDate(string dateString, out DateTime dateTime, TextWriter writer, string errorMessage)
{
    bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                                dateString,
                                "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None,
                                out dateTime);

    if(!isValid)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```